# Failed to decode json

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

hi I want to retrieve json data, the json data is like this

```
"items":[  
  {  
     "date_for":"2018-11-11",
     "fajr":"5:28 am",
     "shurooq":"6:37 am",
     "dhuhr":"11:52 am",
     "asr":"2:40 pm",
     "maghrib":"5:06 pm",
     "isha":"6:15 pm"
  }
],
```

Than I make decodable for JSONDecoder like this:

```
struct PrayerModel: Decodable {
var items: [Items]
}

struct Items: Decodable {
var fajr: String
var dhuhr: String
var asr: String
var maghrib: String
var isha: String

init(dictionary: [String: String]) {
    self.fajr = dictionary["fajr"] ?? ""
    self.dhuhr = dictionary["dhuhr"] ?? ""
    self.asr = dictionary["asr"] ?? ""
    self.maghrib = dictionary["maghrib"] ?? ""
    self.isha = dictionary["isha"] ?? ""
  }
}
```

and then I make an object to store decodable data:

```
struct Prayer {
var prayerName: String
var prayerIcon: UIImage
var prayerTime: String

init(prayerName: String, prayerIcon: UIImage, prayerTime: String) {
    self.prayerName = prayerName
    self.prayerIcon = prayerIcon
    self.prayerTime = prayerTime
 }
}
```

and retrieve it with URLSession:

```
do {
     let prayerData = try JSONDecoder().decode(PrayerModel.self, from: data)

     prayerData.items.forEach({ (item) in
     let isya = Prayer(prayerName: "Isya", prayerIcon: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Clear"), prayerTime: item.isha)
     self.prayers.append(contentsOf: [shubuh, dzuhur, ashar, maghrib, isya])
      })
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
            } catch let decodeErr {
                print("Failed to decode:", decodeErr)
            }
```

and I got this **error**

> Failed to decode: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

where is the problem for my code, anyone can help?

Comment: Read the error message carefully, the problem is not with your code but with the json message that is incorrect. I think it need to be surrounded by a pair of {}. Off topic but I don’t think you need that init method in your Items struct for decoding json

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use Decodable prototype with your JSON, than variables should have exact the same name and include all items with same position.

Try this:

```
var date_for: String
var fajr: String
var shurooq: String
var dhuhr: String
var asr: String
var maghrib: String
var isha: String

init(dictionary: [String: String]) {
    self.date_for = dictionary["date_for"] ?? ""
    self.fajr = dictionary["fajr"] ?? ""
    self.shurooq = dictionary["shurooq"] ?? ""
    self.dhuhr = dictionary["dhuhr"] ?? ""
    self.asr = dictionary["asr"] ?? ""
    self.maghrib = dictionary["maghrib"] ?? ""
    self.isha = dictionary["isha"] ?? ""
}
```

Comment: thank you, I thought since I need only a bit part of data I can skip it. thank you it works!

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question since you do _not_ have to include all the same items so it wouldn't generate an error and definitely not the error in the question.

Comment: @ferryawijayanto, you can skip fields you don’t need.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in my comment the json message is incorrect, I added {} to it and it worked fine.

> {"items":[{
>        "date_for":"2018-11-11",
>        "fajr":"5:28 am",
>        "shurooq":"6:37 am",
>        "dhuhr":"11:52 am",
>        "asr":"2:40 pm",
>        "maghrib":"5:06 pm",
>        "isha":"6:15 pm"
>       }]
>     }

And you do not have to include all elements in the json message if you do not want to use them, I removed the `init()` method from `Items` since it is not used.

```
struct Items: Decodable {
  var fajr: String
  var dhuhr: String
  var asr: String
  var maghrib: String
  var isha: String
}
```

Then it worked perfectly fine with the below code

```
let str = "{\"items\":[{\"date_for\":\"2018-11-11\",\"fajr\":\"5:28 am\",\"shurooq\":\"6:37 am\",\"dhuhr\":\"11:52 am\",\"asr\":\"2:40 pm\",\"maghrib\":\"5:06 pm\",\"isha\":\"6:15 pm\"}]}"

do {
  if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
    let prayerData = try JSONDecoder().decode(PrayerModel.self, from: data)
    for item in prayerData.items {
      print(item)
    }
  }
} catch let decodeErr {
  print("Failed to decode:", decodeErr)
}
```